# R data-manipulation month levels

Tags: r, data-manipulation, levels

I read my PA.csv into R.
But here is a problem:
Why my month levels order like this?

```
levels(PA$Month)
 [1] "1"  "10" "11" "12" "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"
```

If I use this data to draw a plot by *ggplot2*, and x-axis is `PA$Month`, the graphic can show but the values for each month are misordered.
To be more concise, the plot's order shows 1, 10 , 11, 12, 2, 3,..., 9.
How to figure out this?

```
$ Month       : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","10","11",..: 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 2 ...
```

very appreciate.

Comment: they are sorted alphabetically. you can use `as.numeric(as.character(PA$Month))` to fix this, but best to fix the import step

Comment: I don't understand what u mean "best to fix the import step". thanks

Comment: @RichardTelford If I set the format when importing data like this, is it OK?  PA <- read.csv("PA.csv" , header = T , colClasses =  "Month"="numeric")

Comment: or I have to import data and then add  PA$Month <- as.numeric(as.character(PA$Month))

Comment: colClasses might help, but not like that. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` will stop it being a factor. But is will only have happened if there were some characters in the column.

Comment: nice. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exempleDf <- data.frame(month = as.character(c(10:12,1:9)), value= runif(12))
factor(exempleDf$month)
library(ggplot2)
# plot with level in wrong order
qplot(x = month, y = value, data = exempleDf)
# a simple way to reorder factor 
exempleDf$month <- as.factor(as.numeric(exempleDf$month))
factor(exempleDf$month)
# plot with level in right order
qplot(x = month, y = value, data = exempleDf)
factor(exempleDf$month)
```